# An operator which moves on the boundary

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space and $E$ be an orthonormal basis in $H$. 
Let $E_0$ be a countable subset  of $E$ and $p$ be the projection onto the space generated by $E_0$.

Let $\{\zeta_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $H$ and $\{r_n\}$  a sequence of strictly positive numbers.

Question: For given a bounded sequence $\{\eta_n\}$ in $H$, I am looking for an operator $x\in p^{\perp}B(H)$ satisfying in $||x\eta_n-\zeta_n||=r_n$.